How to turn MD5 into hexadecimal?
I am doing an advent of code problem and need to convert MD5 into hex, and I have no clue where to begin.
I tried multiple websites, but none helped, but there were some stack overflow questions that were just confusing.

What you need to do is to convert the secret string into MD5 hash. For that, use the hashlib library:
from hashlib import md5

secret = 'abcdef609043'

print(md5(secret.encode()).hexdigest())

Output:
000001dbbfa3a5c83a2d506429c7b00e

Brief explanation: You first need to get the bytes of the secret string with the .encode method, and then get the hexadecimal representation of the MD5 digest with .hexdigest().

I have a new problem though.

how do i make an integer back into a MD5 Hash?

nevermind, there is already a stackoverflow answer for that.
link
